# python error while reading multiple log files from S3 bucket using boto3 and pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3, boto3

Requirement is : I want to merge all my .log files which are s3 into a single csv file to be placed to a new dir in s3. I'm getting below error.
My log files are very huge, each one has at least 1 lakh records.

```
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 532, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

below is my sample code for this, still i'm working on this.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="output/logs/")

df = []
for obj in objs:
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    temp = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), encoding='utf8')
    df.append(temp)
```

Comment: Are you confident that all your objects in are correct `csv` files? You are trying to iterate over everything there, without checking extentions or size of the objects (empty objects?).

Comment: my objects are .log files and i have 3 log files in the directory each has more than 1 lakh records. now i need to merge them into a single csv file.

Comment: But are the `.log` files in a valid `csv` format?

Comment: Add obj.size check, as you will get folder one of the element in objs.

    `if (obj.size > 0):
      temp = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), encoding='utf8')
      df.append(temp)`